# Powershell replace lose line breaks

Tags: regex, powershell

I am a newbie in powershell. I have a simple powershell script that just replace text but I found that the regex replace turn my multiline data source into a single line text when the output is produced. I want the line breaks to be preserved. Here is the dumb down version of the script.

```
$source=(Get-Content textfile.txt)

$process1 = [regex]::Replace($source, "line", "line2")

$process1 | out-file -encoding ascii textfile2.txt
```

You can create a test file call textfile.txt with simple lines like this to test it

```
line 
line
Some line
More line here
```

Have I missed something obvious?

Thanks,
Fadrian

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your problem here is that `Get-Content` returns a **`string[]`** (with one item for each line in the source file) while `[regex]::Replace` expects a string. That's why the array will first be converted to a string which simply means lumping together all items.

PowerShell provides a `-replace` operator which will handle this case more gracefully:

```
(Get-Content .\textfile.txt) -replace 'line', 'line2' | 
   out-file -encoding ascii textfile2.txt
```

The `-replace` operator operates on each item of an array individually i it's applied to an array.

And yes, it does regular expression matches and replaces. For example:

```
> (Get-Content .\textfile.txt) -replace '(i|o|u)', '$1$1'
liinee
liinee
Soomee liinee
Mooree liinee heeree
```

Read a bit more [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html) and [here](http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/01/17/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-replace-characters-in-a-text-file.aspx).

Comment: This works thanks. Still wonder why the regex behaves the way it is, different from actually running the regex in .NET environment.

Comment: @Fadrian: I added a paragraph at the start of the answer explaining your original problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Johannes +1 for reply and +1 for the post