# Powershell add-content line breaks

Tags: powershell, line-breaks

I am trying to figure out how to eliminate line breaks when using add-content

```
echo $server "Uptime: " $uptime.days ", Days" $uptime.hours ", Hours" $uptime.minutes ", Minutes" | add-content $output_file
```

Basically I have been trying to get the uptime of a server to go to a text file, and when I do this the output comes out

```
HOSTNAME
Uptime:
, 2 Days
2 
, Hours
15
, Minutes
```

I looked at this question: [Powershell replace lose line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726599/powershell-replace-lose-line-breaks)

Also I went from using out-file -append to add-content, however both produce similar results, can someone shed to some light on how I can eliminate the breaks?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you want to have one line with the info, then:

```
"$server Uptime: $($uptime.days) Days, $($uptime.hours) Hours, $($uptime.minutes) Minutes" | add-content $output_file
```

If every item should be on separate line, you might add *`n*

```
"$server Uptime`n$($uptime.days) Days`n$($uptime.hours) Hours`n$($uptime.minutes) Minutes" | add-content $output_file
```

Other possibility is to use `-f` which is sometimes more readable:

```
"$server Uptime: {0} Days, {1} Hours, {2} Minutes" -f $uptime.days, $uptime.hours, $uptime.minutes | add-content $output_file
```

**Update**
`echo` is alias for `Write-Output` (`Get-Alias -name echo`) which in your case produces array of objects. This array is passed to `Add-Content`; each object is stored on its own line.

Comment: Thank you, this worked well! It also gave me a better understanding of what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Added info about what caused the line breaks :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to sidestep any problem PowerShell might be putting into the line breaks would be to avoid using the providers.

By using [IO.File]::WriteAllText to write the file, you should be able to avoid the linebreaks that come from PowerShell.  The only caveat is that [IO.File]::WriteAllText doesn't understand PowerShell paths, so you'll need to pass it an absolute path.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
[IO.File]::AppendAllText($testfile,"abc",[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
```