# Powershell Regex to Find and Remove a Function

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to find a function in a few hundred pages and remove it using Powershell.  I can match on a single line but I'm having issues getting a multi-line match to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Function I'm trying to find:

```
Protected Function MyFunction(ByVal ID As Integer) As Boolean
    Return list.IsMyFunction()  
End Function
```

Code I'm using that won't match multi-line:

```
gci -recurse | ?{$_.Name -match "(?i)MyPage.*\.aspx"} | %{
  $c = gc $_.FullName;
  if ($c -match "(?m)Protected Function MyFunction\(ByVal ID As Integer\) As Boolean.*End Function")  {
    $_.Fullname | write-host;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `(?s)` flag on the regex. S for singleline, also called, dotall in some places, which makes `.` match across newlines.

Also, `gc` reads line by line and any comparision / match will be between individual lines and the regex. You will not get a match despite using proper flags on the regex. I usually use `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText()` to get the entire file's contents as a single string.

So a working solution will be something like:

```
gci -recurse | ?{$_.Name -match "(?i)MyPage.*\.aspx"} | %{
  $c = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.Fullname)
  if ($c -match "(?s)Protected Function MyFunction\(ByVal ID As Integer\) As Boolean.*End Function")  {
    $_.Fullname | write-host;
  }

}
```

For the replace, you can of course use `$matches[0]` and use the `Replace()` method

```
$newc = $c.Replace($matches[0],"")
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the -match operator will not search for .* through carriage returns. You will need to use the .Net Regex.Match function directly to specify the 'singleline' (unfortunately named in this case) search option:

```
[Regex]::Match($c,
               "(?m)Protected Function MyFunction\(ByVal ID As Integer\) As Boolean.*End Function", 
               'Singleline')
```

See the [Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk1x0726.aspx) function and [valid regex options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) in the MSDN for more details.

Comment: This solution works great for search.  The reason I didn't choose it as the answer is that I then had a problem with writing the content back out.  To use the .net [regex]::replace function would strip out line breaks, while the solution I marked as the answer fixes the search issue and also preserves the formatting for set-content.  For more details, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726599/powershell-replace-lose-line-breaks  Thanks again.