# Read and Write HTML file in Batch Script

Tags: html, batch-file

I'll confess that I was never all that good at writing DOS Batch scripts beyond basic stuff.
I've had need to write a script to read an HTML template file and create a new file from it... Now I can read the file into a variable using:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (template.html) do set fileData=%%x
```

and I can echo the variable out to see that the html data is in there.
But when I try to write it out using:

```
echo %fileData%>test2.html
```

I get an error:

**The system cannot find the file specified.**

I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the variable containing html tags that are confusing the output to file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, the `<` and `>` tag characters are being evaluated literally by `echo %fileData%`.  Use the delayed expansion style to prevent that from happening..  Put `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the top of your script and `echo !fileData!>test2.html`.

As a side note, you might benefit from a [batch script heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15032476/1683264) for composing your HTML.  If you're comfortable with JavaScript and you're feeling adventurous, it's also possible to [interact with the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28633248/1683264) by calling Windows Scripting Host methods in a hybrid script.

One other note: If you

```js
for /f "delims=" %%x in (template.html) do set fileData=%%x
```

your `fileData` variable gets reset over and over for each line in `template.html`, until it ultimately ends up containing only the last line.  Batch variables can't (easily) contain multiple lines.  You need to do your processing within the loop, something like this:

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
    for /f "delims=" %%x in (template.html) do (
        set "fileData=%%x"
        echo !fileData:search=replace!
    )
)>test2.html
```

Comment: Thanks rojo, that almost does it for me... For some reason, I now only get the last line of the file, so the echo of !fileData! returns </html>, so it seems to have discarded all the file contents, except for the last line. Maybe I need a different method for reading in the file to my variable?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help! The only thing I had to do was use >>test2.html at the end, though, since >test2.html only wrote the last line of my file.

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this for the past ~2 hours, just to discover that it can be done in one line:

```
 type file.html>>otherFile.html
```

As far as I know, it should work with any file extension (as long as the type command works with it). I'm not sure if this completely suits your needs but it's a pretty neat way to append a file's content to another file.
P.S.: Don't judge me if I made a mistake, I'm also a batch script newbie.