# Batch file find a string

Tags: batch-file

How can i get a word from a file and set it to a variabile for ex:

The text file contains bunch of text and i want to find only one word with the 4 or 5 random characters behind it

Fatbardh: 79%

Now i want to get that Fatbardh word but the 79% could be random number it can
be any number, i want to get that random number and set it to an variable

can someone help me
the text file is pretty long with a lot of words as well not only
containing one word i dont know how to do it

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please read at least the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how this site works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the string token in the line you're searching for, you can use `FOR /F` to process the output of the `FINDSTR` command.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%a in ('findstr /i "Fatbardh" "YourFile.txt"') do set percent=%%a
echo %percent%
```

If you don't want the % symbol in the variable, include it in the delimiters.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:%% " %%a in ('findstr /i "Fatbardh" "YourFile.txt"') do set percent=%%a
echo %percent%
```

Comment: Here is a text file on the link below. Somewhere on that text file there is a "Mastery:" word without quotes close to that there is a percentage number that can be a random number, in this case it is 33% i want to get that percentage number and set it to a variabile
I want to thank you for your answer =)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3FOapm5Vb56aXdNdmhmQkEtRXc

Comment: You're dealing with markup. This might be a better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893147/need-to-parse-out-string-from-html-document-in-a-batch-file